# iphone - take screenshot of another app?

Tags: iphone, screenshot

Would it be possible to have my app take a screenshot of another app?  For instance, to make some sort of "screenshotter" application?

I know you can take a screenshot of any UIView, but would it be possible to *get* any UIView?  For instance, another app, or what's running below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not possible. Even if you had a really pressing reason to want this, it would be a humongous security hole.

Comment: Well there goes that idea! Thanks!